# Capturing contents of a table row without adding directive to each row

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angular application, a Directive called CaptureMovements is responsble for highlighing a row and capturing it's content.

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in body" capture-movements='{{element}}' >
```

This can also be observed in the file layout.html in the following plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fB8RLOXpkiUZqRzhTKfj

So if you run the plnkr, then hit g and then 1 (g+1) on the keyboard you will notice that a row is highlighted. Eveytime you hit g and then 1 another row is highlighted.

Now if the table has hundreds of rows, this slows down the application (must be the broadcast and receive mechanism).

Ideally, how is such an issue meant to be resolved in angular ?

any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS way would be to add a directive to each row and react to the key stroke event as you have done. There are multiple ways that don't involve "broadcasting" the keystroke event but it does involve placing each directive on the individual rows - it could be a custom directive as is in your case or perhaps the `ng-class` directive which conditionally applies classes.

Either way, you will face performance problems with large number of rows due to the amount of watchers placed.

The simplest way would be to go the native Javascript way.
Consider this - assume that your application does not use AngularJS. Don't even think of jQuery.

Now, how would you write your javascript code to carry out the same function?
Initially start by selecting all n rows of the table and store it.

```
var tableRows = document.getElementById('myCustomTable')
                        .getElementByTagName('tr');
```

This will select all rows of the table. Yes, it will be performance intensive but not as much as placing individual directives on each row.

Now, have an event handler for the keystroke element that will then apply the border to the nth row and remove the border from the (n-1)th row. You dont' have to fetch the nth row each time since you fetched it earlier and have stored it.

Comment: @katootie .. once i have tableRows.. what function can I use to add a class to a specific row during runtime ?